# How to change value of multiple text inputs using class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to change multiple text inputs (but not all) by class, but can't seem to get it working.

Any ideas?

Basically I have multiple reset buttons on the same page I'd like to have 'resetting' the value of the targeted text inputs to nothing.

Here's the code:

```
$(".reset").on('click', function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('input-1').value = '';
});
```

It works fine when using getElementById, but I would rather minimise the code and not have to repeat it each time for every text input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already using jQuery, so just use

```
$(".reset").on('click', function() {
  $('.input-1').val('');
});
```

Notice the `.` before the class name, same as in `.reset`.

If you want to use vanilla JavaScript, you have to loop through the HTMLCollection returned by `getElementsByClassName`:

```
$(".reset").on('click', function() {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('input-1')).forEach(el => el.value = '');
});
```

jQuery does that automatically for you.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('input-1').forEach(el => el.value = '');` won't work. Method `getElementsByClassName` returns `NodeList` that doesn't have `forEach` method. NodeList should be converted to an Array using `Array.from` method or `Array.prototype.forEach` method should be applied on `NodeList` via `call` or `apply`.

Comment: It does have [a forEach method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach), but you are right, it's not really well supported.

Comment: You're right. I've mixed up `NodesList` and `HTMLCollection`. `getElementsByClassName` returns `HTMLCollection` and it doesn't have `forEach` method.

Comment: I don't think you can still do that. But since IE doesn't support fE on HTMLCollections, using array.from makes sense here :-)

Comment: I've just checked in Chrome Canary 71 and got the following error: `VM259:1 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).forEach is not a function`

Comment: Strange, MDN says it's supported in C >= 51

Comment: Why it's strange? The link you've posted leads to `NodeList.prototype.forEach` method description. It works in modern browsers. But `getElementsByClassName` returns [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) instead of `NodeList`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an special selector for this job:

```
let inputs = [... document.querySelectorAll("[class^='input-']")];

inputs.forEach(i  => i.value = "");
```

class^= will return all the elements containing class attribute starting with "input".

Comment: This won't work. You cannot set a value to a `NodeList` that's returned from `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: This will not work, the return value of `querySelectorAll` does not have a value attribute as it's an array-like structure with HTML elements in it